# System.Net.Http.HttpClient.PostAsync not working in .net3.5 but in 4.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-3.5, httpclient

I have the following code which is working fine on .NET 4.0. But when I changed the target framework to .NET3.5, it runs without any errors, but not doing the upload.

When debugged its skipping from the line `resp.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` and never executes the lines below or at-least the catch block.

(By the way I've added System.Net.Http to .net 3.5 from here since httpclient is not shipped with .net3.5 - 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rackspace.HttpClient35/1.0.0-beta003)

```
public string pp(string bb,string code,string kb)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                MultipartFormDataContent formx = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                formx.Add(new StringContent(code), "fn");
                var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(kb);
                string kbb= System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
                formx.Add(new StringContent(kbb), "kb");

                formx.Add(new StringContent(bb), "img");  

                var resp = httpClient.PostAsync("http://s.*****.com/put.php", formx);

                resp.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                httpClient.Dispose();
                string rep = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return rep;
            }
            catch (Exception ee) {
                return "no";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, but the strangest part is that I can successfully perform a `GetAsync` call, but the `PostAsync` and `SendAsync` methods hang.

Comment: I believe I found that there is a known bug with the Rackspace.HttpClient35 library: https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/dotnet-httpclient35/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

I think postasync is available with new version. you can find document with provide they need framework atleast 4.0

for more detail please go with below link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

Comment: It compiles without any errors at all. By the way I've added System.Net.Http to .net 3.5 from here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rackspace.HttpClient35/1.0.0-beta001

Comment: i have go with given link and i think this is different httpclint dll because they depend on rackspce.this is not part of .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` meaning `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` was not introduced until version .Net 4.0. Therefore it shouldnt even compile.

It is possible that your project is not properly rebuilt (clean \ build) as the compiler should not allow you to build the project.

Comment: It compiles without any errors at all. By the way I've added System.Net.Http to .net 3.5 from here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rackspace.HttpClient35/1.0.0-beta001

Comment: That would be good information to add to the post as `HttpClient` doesnt exist and you are using a 3rd party tool.